# Reading and Writing from an XML file in Java

Tags: java, servlets

I've created an XML file in java , the XML file consists of movie names , their release dates and trailer , Writing the XML file is not a problem but when I'm trying to read from the XML file with a servlet the browser is not displaying not a single information from the XML file , no errors are appearing , the code is running but the for some reason it's not reading from the file , I'm using the DOM parser method to read and write , can anyone please tell me what's wrong with the way I'm reading the XML file ?

Here's the XML file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<cinema>
  <Movie id="10">
    <Name>Army of Thieves</Name>
    <Genre>Comedy/Action</Genre>
    <Director>Matthias Schweighöfer</Director>
    <releaseDate>29/10/2021</releaseDate>
    <Trailer>https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ith2WetKXlg</Trailer>
</Movie>
    <Movie id="11">
    <Name>Dune</Name>
    <Genre>Sci-Fi/Adventure</Genre>
    <Director> Denis Villeneuve</Director>
    <releaseDate>16/09/2021</releaseDate>
    <Trailer>https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n9xhJrPXop4</Trailer>
</Movie>
</cinema>
```

Here's the servlet :

```
import java.io.*;

import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;

public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws 
ServletException,IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    try {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse("/movies.xml"); //put the xml path here
        NodeList elements = doc.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagName("Movie");

        out.println("<table><tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Genre</th><th>Director</th> 
 <th>releaseDate</th><th>Trailer</th></tr>");
        if(elements.getLength() == 0){
            out.println("<tr><td>No information</td></tr>");
        }
        else{
            for(int i = 0; i < elements.getLength(); i++){
                out.println("<tr> 
 <td>"+elements.item(i).getAttributes().item(0).getTextContent()+"</td>"+
                        " 
 <td>"+elements.item(i).getChildNodes().item(0).getTextContent()+"</td>"+
                        " 
 <td>"+elements.item(i).getChildNodes().item(1).getTextContent()+"</td></tr>");
            }
        }
        out.println("</table>");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I recommend stepping through this with a debugger to find out what's happening.

Comment: First, you should change e.printStackTrace() to `throw new RuntimeException(e);`.  That way, you will know for certain whether an error is occurring.  Second, don’t use `getAttributes()` or `getChildNodes()`.  Sometimes a document parser adds attributes, and child nodes are more than just elements.  Use `getAttribute("id")`, `getElementByTagName("Name")`, `getElementByTagName("Genre")`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You say your code is not reading from the file. How do you know it is not reading from the file? Is there some exception? Do you see data that should not be there?

I usually try to know the exact location that my code is looking for files. Therefore my pattern looks like

```
File infile = new File("/movies.xml");
log.debug("Reading file "+infile.getAbsolutePath());
Document doc = builder.parse(new FileInputStream(infile));
```

Regardless whether the path is correct or not, in the logfile I will understand at runtime which file was loaded. Based on that I can then check if it is a wrong location (and therefure just another file that gets read), or permissions are not set, or the file does not exist, ...